# Remap a single key press while keeping default shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, remapping

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and, unfortunately, my keyboard doesn't have a Left <kbd>Super</kbd>. As I never use <kbd>Alt</kbd> alone (always in a combination), I would like to remap a single <kbd>Alt</kbd> key press to <kbd>Super</kbd> (showing the activities view), but keep shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> untouched.
Is it possible? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question! But do notice that some programs react immediately to Super (i.e., they act on the keypress, not waiting for the key release). That would be a problem if you managed to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to install the package xcape and configure the keys as required.

`sudo apt install xcape`

> Description: Configure modifier keys to act as other keys when pressed
> and released xcape allows you to use a modifier key as another key
> when pressed and released on its own. Note that it is slightly slower
> than pressing the original key, because the pressed event does not
> occur until the key is released. The default behaviour is to generate
> the Escape key when Left Control is pressed and released on its own.

once `xcape` is installed run the below command to make Left Alt work as Left Super

`xcape -e 'Alt_L=Super_L'`

then test it, If yes.. add the command to startup application preferences..

xcape is bit laggy or in good words it requires milliseconds time to work..
so when you press and release Alt_L key, it acts as Super_L and when you Press Alt_L and dont release, Alt+Tab or Alt+` or any combo with Alt_L will work..

read manual page

```
man xcape
```